# Is it possible to generate one signed URL for a folder and upload multiple files into it?

Tags: signed-url, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to use GCS signed url like "{gcs_domain}/anybucket/folder1/?{gcs_headers}" to upload multiple times different fils (with one or more requests, it doesn't matter)?

and finally it gives :
-folder1
--file1.txt
--file2.txt
...

Or the Signed Url is strictly paired with one object?

I've looked at the Signed Url doc, but didn't find this info.

Thanks.